# Enforcing order of jQuery UI transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

I'm working on a site using Twitter bootstrap and the Ace Admin template.
Dropdown menus are implemented using unordered lists in which each list item is an element in the dropdown.

My user requirement is that the dropdown list show a list of notifications and when a notification is clicked, the list of notifications will slide away and the details of the clicked notification will slide into place. I implement all the content as list items and use jquery-ui's hide and show functions to animate the transitions.

The basic flow is supposed to be:
User Clicks notification -> list of notifications is hidden -> Notification detail is shown.
User Clicks "back on detail -> notification detail is hidden -> Notification List is shown.

For some reason, the first scenario above works fine, but in the second, the notification list starts to show before the details are done being hidden, which results in the parent container getting temporarily taller as both are visible.

Here is how I have the code:

```
$(".notification-item").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var guid = $(e.target).closest("li").attr("data-guid");

    $(".notification-item").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 250, function () {
        // This is called when hiding is complete
        // show the back button and detail for the correct notification
        $("#notificationsBack").add("li#" + guid).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 250);              
    });
});

$("#notificationsBack").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".notification-detail").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 250, function () {
        // this functions should run after the hide is complete, but appears to start immediately
        $(".notification-item").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 250);
    });
});
```

I've [posted a video of how this looks](http://youtu.be/VAKFRWfv2LM) (with the animation slowed down for better visibility).

Any idea why in the second transition the hide actions doesn't complete before the show action starts?

Comment: Is there a reason you put the `$(".notification-item").show(…)` inside of the `.hide()` block?

Comment: Yes, it's in the callback function that should be called when the .hide completes. The function declaration is at the end of the line above.

Comment: I know, but that isn't necessary. If anything, just do `setTimeout(function(){$(".notification-item").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 250)}, 250);` if you want to make sure it starts after the other one.

Comment: Ah, I see. That does work. I'll go with that although I wish I knew why the callback wasn't being called at the right time. If you want to submit it as an answer I'll accept it so you can get the reputation.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's because it's immediately evaluated as okay, so it moves on to the next function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to force the `.show()` event to happen after the other one. The easiest way to do this is with:

```
$("#notificationsBack").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".notification-detail").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 250);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".notification-item").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 250);
    }, 250);
});
```

a `setTimeout()` call.